# GitHub Azure Synapse Access issue: You don't have permission to import resource to the repository, please resolve the permissions in GitHub

Tags: github, azure-synapse

When I attempt to connect to GitHub repository from Azure Data Factory I have no problem. However, when I try to connet to GitHub from Synapse, see image, I get the error:

[image]

> You don't have permission to import resource to the repository, please
> resolve the permissions in GitHub

I'm not sure why I'm not getting the same permissions error message ADF

Just so you know I have the following permissions configured for Synapse, but it I'm still getting the error:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I connected the ***GitHub repository*** from ***Azure Synapse*** and **Azure Data factory** it’s working fine for me.

If you have an ***Existing resource*** to the repository in ***GitHub*** mentioned in ***import branch***, otherwise make sure to **unmark it**. Because of that, you are getting the error as seen in the above image.

[image: Ref1]

If you have already ***connected to GitHub*** and only ***granted permission*** to access a personal account, follow the below steps to ***grant permissions*** to an ***organization***

Go to ***GitHub*** and open ***Settings*** -> Select ***Applications***. In the ***Authorized OAuth apps tab***, you should see ***Azure Synapse*** > ***Select the Azure Synapse*** and ***grant the access*** to your ***organization***

[image: ref2]

[image: Ref3]

**Reference:**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/data-factory/source-control#author-with-github-integration

Comment: Hey @Patterson, I did reproduce this issue and the solution worked for me; do let me know if it solved your problem else share more details so I can troubleshoot?